# testing gamekit framework on a simulator

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, wifi, p2p, gamekit

I'm trying to test whether I am using gamekit properly using a simulator. Is it possible for a simulator running my code to detect an external ipad or iphone if they are with in range using the gamekit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GameKit app in the simulator can connect to a version of it on the iPad/iPhone/iPad if both are on the same Wireless LAN.

Comment: so theres no way to test it if the computer and the device is paired by bluetooth only? I have to have them connected to wifi?

Comment: GameKit uses TCP/IP. If "paired by Bluetooth only" means actual tethering, then it should work over Bluetooth, too. Asides, you can always setup a private Wifi network on your Mac and join it with the iPad.